# How to write the single xpath when the text is in two lines

Tags: xpath, robotframework

How to write the single  xpath for this

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 profilesky"> <div class="career_icon"> 
          <span> Boost </span> <br/>
          Your Profile </div>
```

I am able to write by two line using "contains" method.

```
.//*[contains(text(),'Boost')] 
.//*[contains(text(),'Your Profile')]
```

But i want in a single line to write the xpath for this.

Comment: Does `.//[contains(text(),'Boost')][contains(text(),'Your Profile')]` work?

Comment: s it works .. by using element should contains

Comment: Your Profile is next line ,"Boost
Your Profile"

Comment: @KarthikaItsYourSkills tips: select/block your code -> click `{}` on top

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way :

```
.//*[@class='career_icon' and contains(., 'Boost') and contains(., 'Your Profile')]
```

Above xpath check if there is an element having class attribute equals `career_icon` and contains both `Boost` and `Your Profile` texts in the element body.

Note that `text()` only checks direct child text node. To check entire text content of an element simply use dot (`.`).

Comment: It's worse than that - `contains(text(), 'xyz')` checks only the _first_ direct child text node and ignores all the others.

Comment: element should contains  xpath=.//*[@class='career_icon' and contains(., 'Boost') and contains(., 'Your Profile')]    Boost Your Profile

Comment: @KarthikaItsYourSkills that isn't valid xpath, so I don't understand what you actually mean, especially the trailing " Boost Your Profile" part

Comment: I want To check whether the text is present der in a single xpath    .when i write like this it gives error                                                                                             element should contains               xpath=.//*[@class='career_icon' and contains(., 'Boost') and contains(., 'Your Profile')]      Boost Your Profile

Comment: @KarthikaItsYourSkills you're keep repeating the same words "*element should contains xpath=.//*[@class='career_icon' and contains(., 'Boost') and contains(., 'Your Profile')] Boost Your Profile*". That isn't valid xpath so I don't understand what the element should actually contains... How about explaining what's the problem when using xpath I suggested in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine several rules just by writing them one after another since they refer to the same element:

```
.//[contains(text(),'Boost')][contains(text(),'Your Profile')]
```

Comment: what r the rules?How should i check elements is present r not?                  Element should contains   xpath=.//*[@class='career_icon']    Boost your carrer

Comment: Element should contains   xpath=.//*[@class='career_icon']    Boost your Profile. It gives error when i give the xpath like this. because "your profile "is on next line

Comment: @Karthika no, the syntax error is because you're missing a `*` between `//` and `[`, but it will fail to match anyway because the two conditions `contains(text(),'Boost')` and `contains(text(),'Your Profile')` cannot both be satisfied by the same element. Use `.` instead of `text()` as suggested by the other answer.

Comment: I tried it but its giving invalid .  element text should be  .//*[contains(.,'Boost')] and [contains(.,'Your Profile')]   Boost Your Profile  what are the possible ways i can give know. can any one share your idea.